# Priority in execution sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a kind of priority code on a sql query.

It should go like this, I have 4 conditions,

```
ID number, 
Name, 
Alias **and** born date,
```

so the query should be as following, if I have the `ID number`, `display Name`, `Alias` **and** `born date` plus social security, size, place he/she live of that ID number.

If the ID number is empty, go for the Name, and display the same (obvious, except the ID number).

If the name is empty go for Alias. I also have an **and** condition, which is born date at the end of the query

So far, I have the following:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Alias, Place, social security, size
FROM [Main].[FacilityInformation]
WHERE ID in ('01957TA45') 
or Name IN ('James') 
or Alias in ('Jay') 
**and** Born_date ('1980-07-28')
```

I am not completly sure if this is working as I wish.

Thank you,

Comment: if you have only 1 condition for a where clause, don't use `IN` but use `=` -> `ID = '01957TA45'`

Comment: Well, if you are not sure, then test it on your data! You know your data, you know your requirements.

Comment: @Shadow I did, but look, I got a table with not only the id number '01957TA45' but other ids associate it with the name, James, alias, Jay, and  born date, so is not like "filtering" the date but taking all conditions.

Comment: @Cid I did for ID, but you mean for all conditions?

Comment: @Gabriel yes, with `id` it was just an example

Answer (score 0):

You missed the brackets for the ORs:

```
WHERE (ID in ('01957TA45') 
or Name IN ('James') 
or Alias in ('Jay'))
AND Born_date in ('1980-07-28')
```

Comment: Yes, you got that rigth, it definetly change the results. Thank you man